# how is TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (1, 'j'), 'jsp') taking 1 as the input it should take in parameter as date?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

could not able to understand

select     TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (1, 'j'), 'jsp') from dual;

how is to_date and to_char taking them as parameter.
sometimes to_date takes date as input sometimes not??

Answer (score 1):

TO_DATE would accept a string that represents a date that matches the format string you provide.  In this case, you have provided 'J' as the format string, which tells Oracle the data represents a number of julian days.  Perfectly valid.  I suggest that you not call TO_DATE with a DATE as the data element, if you feel the need to convert a DATE into a DATE again, use CAST.